# Parse URL to search Pattern

Tags: python

I need to read URL content and search/regex for a pattern. e.g. in corrupt_files.jsp, I need to search for any keyword "auction_log.DATE" (where DATE is yesterday)

How can I achieve it?

Below is what I got so far:

```
from urllib import urlopen
import re
import time
import datetime
from datetime import date, timedelta
yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)

DATE= yesterday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

html = urlopen("http://url.com/corrupt_files.jsp").read()

for line in html.split('<tr'):
  re.search('auction_log.DATE',line)
```

Comment: You do know you [shouldn't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2308683), right?

Comment: And start with `'auction_log.{}'.format(DATE)` to get the correct string

Comment: @cricket_007 is absolutely correct.  Use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: @all, how do I use HTML parser code suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) to extract your content. For example with BS:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('corrupt_files.jsp').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
soup.body.findAll(text='auction_log.DATE')
```